# Fetch Full Address based on Postal Code via Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

[image]

I would like to grab the address highlighted in red. "Site Location:" can be easily identified via match(). However, how can I grab the highlighted part only without going over proceeding content, i.e., "You have applied...etc". Please note that the proceeding content won't always start with "You have applied".

What I would do is the following:

1. Look for "Site Location:"
2. Grab anything after "Site Location:" until you find empty/blank new line.

Can anyone help me achieving it in Ruby?

Note that the whole text is stored in a string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regex = /\bSite Location:\s+(.*?)\n\s*\n/m

str = "Site Location:   Raglan Street
                        Collingwood Town, Some County

You have applied..."

if md = regex.match(str)
  address = md[1].strip.gsub(/^\s+/,'')
  puts address
end
```

Output:

```
Raglan Street
Collingwood Town, Some County
```

Note: one thing to watch for is the possibility of different types of newlines. E.g. Microsoft may use `\r\n\r\n`, etc. in which case you may have to adjust `regex` accordingly.